# Why is the dblGrossPay line not a statement ';' expected error?

Tags: java

```
package mp1.mod3.icsc103.cbm;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MP1MOD3ICSC103CBM {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       double dblGrossPay;
       final double dblHoursWork= 30, dblHoursOT= 10, dblHoursLate =5, dblRatePH=250 ;
       Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        
       System.out.println("Employee Number: 001");
       System.out.println("First Name: Clarence");
       System.out.println("Last Name: Mantua");
       
       dblGrossPay = ((dblHoursWork + dblHoursOT) – dblHoursLate) * dblRatePH ;
    } 
}
```

The code `dblGrossPay = ((dblHoursWork + dblHoursOT) – dblHoursLate) \* dblRatePH` has an error that says it's not a statement.

Comment: You're using an en dash instead of a minus.

Comment: It's good practice to read the _first_ error, not the last one: https://godbolt.org/z/8xn4YnWGK

Answer (score 2):

`–` is not a minus sign. It's U+2013, called "en dash". `-` is a minus sign.

Answer (score 0):

You added an illegal character in your expression:

```
MP1MOD3ICSC103CBM.java:14: error: ')' expected
       dblGrossPay = ((dblHoursWork + dblHoursOT) ΓÇô dblHoursLate) * dblRatePH ;
```

You meant "-" (minus sign").

Retype the expression - and it should fix the compile error.